# Journey – overnight stay – return home. On return trip, when to say Tefilas Haderekh?

Tags: halacha, tefilat-haderech

[Mishna Berurah 110 (70) [29]](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.110.29?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> that although we say Tefilas Haderekh when we have left town, that's
>   only at the beginning of the trip but when we stay overnight on the
>   way, we can say THD when we get ready to leave even though we are
>   still in town, because we have already started on the journey
>   (*yesterday*).
>
> וכ"ז בתחלת יציאתו מביתו אבל כשהוא לן בדרך יוכל לומר תה"ד בבוקר כשמכין
>   עצמו לצאת אפילו כשהוא עדיין בעיר דכבר החזיק בדרך

That is understandable if we are traveling further onward on the second day; but can we say THD in town when we are returning home on the second day?

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what you do not understand? Is your question regarding saying THD once you arrive back in town or while still in the town you are visiting?

Comment: Day 1, I travel from Manchester to London. I stay overnight in London and day 2 I travel back to Manchester. I say THD when outside Manchester on day 1. When do I say THD on day 2? Do I have to be out of London or can I say it when in London?

Comment: I do not see why there would be a difference when he is headed home or headed onward.

Comment: @GershonGold Heading onwards can be thought of as part of the same trip. Heading home implies you got to your destination and are starting again.

Comment: @DoubleAA: תחלת יציאתו מביתו means when you leave your house. Not when you are leaving from the guest house.

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought I remembered from a shiur like Gershon Gold says but as we can see from both your comments, the text is open to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is one of translation:

> וכ"ז בתחלת יציאתו מביתו אבל כשהוא לן בדרך יוכל לומר תה"ד בבוקר כשמכין
> עצמו לצאת אפילו כשהוא עדיין בעיר דכבר החזיק בדרך

*And all this (what was said before) is at the start of his leaving from his house, **but** when he stays (sleeps over) along the way he can say tefilas haderech in the morning when he "arouses himself" to leave, even though he is still in the town (where he stayed over) because he has already established himself (literally strengthened) on the trip.*

Thus, until one arrives home, it is considered that he is still traveling. In your example, once he leaves Manchester, every following day is considered part of the trip until he gets home. Leaving London (even to go home to Manchester) is not a separate trip.

[When to Say Tefilas Haderech](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/289763/jewish/When-to-Say-Tefilas-Haderech.htm) actually speaks about this.

> 20. If one has in mind to stay overnight at a certain location when reciting Tefilas Haderech and after arriving and stopping at that
>     location he changes his mind and continues further or returns home, he
>     must repeat Tefilas Haderech.
>
> שו"ע או"ח סימן ק"י סעיף ה'

As we see above traveling home is considered part of the trip.

Comment: What if he spends a month in London. Then is the trip back separate? Why?

Comment: @DoubleAA Halacha 17 and 18 in the linked citation deal with this issue. There are those who do not say it on non-traveling days and resume when traveling (but still as part of the same trip) and those who say it every day (as part of shma koleinu) because they are still considered "traveling"